# How to download an attachment from couchdb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, download, couchdb

I am using nodejs with couchdb nano npm package in backend and angularjs in fronted. I want to download attachment of couchdb.

Server Side: Route is /fileupload/downloadDbDoc/:doc_id/:doc_name

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

let data = await  students_db.attachment.get(doc_id, doc_name);
let filePath = path.join('tempfiles',doc_name);
fs.writeFile(filePath, data, function (err) {
    if (!err){
        const file = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg; image/jpg; image/png; ');
        res.setHeader(
        'Content-Disposition',
        'attachment; filename="' + doc_name + '"'
        );
        file.pipe(res);
    }

});
```

Client Side

```
$scope.downloadDoc = function (doc_id, doc_name) {

  $http.post('/fileupload/downloadDbDoc/' + doc_id + '/' + doc_name, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    let headers = response.headers();
    headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment';
    let blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'octet/stream' });
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = docname;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);

  }, function (errorRes) {
    console.log(errorRes);
  });

};
```

When I execute this code,  Download get started. But problem is that when I open this downloaded file it shows **Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xef 0xbf)**
And file is not open as I want.

Comment: You are writing the file locally to `tempfiles` - does the temp file also begin with `0xef 0xbf`? As an aside, sending two different mime types - `image/jpg; image/png;` - is questionable.

Comment: tempfiles is my folder name.My approach is that first I create file in tempfiles folder further I will delete all files of tempfiles folder by using cronjob.  I am using nano couchdb package. Is there any way to download this attachment without writing this file locally. My file type can be anything so I have no idea about what should I use in mime type.

Comment: It would be a valuable step to verify the attachment by inspecting the header of a temporary file, for example a JPEG must start with FFD8.  This is valuable because you can verify the attachment itself is correct.  Anyway, you should be able to pipe the attachment stream with nano's attachment method `getAsStream` without having a temporary file.